# Costs of B2C and Refresh tokens

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-ad-b2c

I'm not sure I'm understanding this properly, but here goes:

Since MSA and Google tokens expire every hour, the only way for my app to reflect changes in the user's permissions on the MSA and Google site would be to refresh the EasyAuth B2C token on roughly the same interval, right?  If they revoke access to my app, then they probably don't want unexpired tokens rolling around for days.

And each time I need to refresh that token, another refresh call is made to B2C and then on to the identity provider, right?

And each time that happens I'll be charged (based on the info on the Azure pricing page).  So if my app (it's a financial app with the ability to charge credit cards) gets popular and scales, the fees will be actually quite large, as there will be tons of logging in/out and refreshing if everyone is responsible.

Do I have this right?  Any suggestions for mitigating the fees responsibly?

Does the refresh token store get purged when someone logs out?  If so, then I could just assume (I know - bad word) that if they want to disable access to the app, they just logout.  Any subsequent login or use of a refresh token would then be blocked.

Answer (score 1):

> > Since MSA and Google tokens expire every hour, the only way for my app to reflect changes in the user's permissions on the MSA and Google site would be to refresh the EasyAuth B2C token on roughly the same interval, right?

Based on my understanding, web application used the id_token to authenticate the user. After the web application authenticated, it contains its own session and the default web application session time is 1440 minutes, we can config it. You can refer here for the detail.

And if you were using the OAuth 2.0 flow to authorize the application to access the resource which protected by Azure AD, since the life time of token is one hour if it is expired we need to renew the token as you mentioned.

> > And each time I need to refresh that token, another refresh call is made to B2C and then on to the identity provider, right?
> >     And each time that happens I'll be charged (based on the info on the Azure pricing page). So if my app (it's a financial app with the ability to charge credit cards) gets popular and scales, the fees will be actually quite large, as there will be tons of logging in/out and refreshing if everyone is responsible.
> >     Do I have this right? Any suggestions for mitigating the fees responsibly?

You were right. Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) B2C usage will be billed monthly based on the total number of both: Stored Users, Authentications: Tokens issued either in response to a sign-in request initiated by a user, or initiated by an application on behalf of a user (e.g. token refresh, where the refresh interval is configurable).

> > Does the refresh token store get purged when someone logs out? If so, then I could just assume (I know - bad word) that if they want to disable access to the app, they just logout. Any subsequent login or use of a refresh token would then be blocked.

Did you mean revoke the token? The log out the web application won’t revoke the token. Azure AD doesn’t support revoking the token at present. However, we can clear the token cache if you doesn’t want users to user the token.