# Revoke a refresh token on Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

I don't know if there is a solution to revoke a refresh token when :
- a user reset its own password with the reset password policy ?
- a user change its own password with a specific form based on Graph API ?

I think it must be implemented for security reason but I don't if it's possible for now and if not when will it be available ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Any news about this feature ? I also tried to do a reset password on web app and on an ios sample application, I'm still able to get new tokens without having to use my new password...

Answer (score 3):

I found a similar questions to your question [Costs of B2C and Refresh tokens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39477763/costs-of-b2c-and-refresh-tokens?rq=1).

The essential part of the answer from the other question is:

> The log out the web application won’t revoke the token. Azure AD doesn’t support revoking the token at present. However, we can clear the token cache if you doesn’t want users to user the token.

I did some own tests using the Azure AD Graph API and was unable to get the refresh token to expire, even when resetting the password of the user accessing the resources.

As far as I know, there doesn't seem to be any way to expire the token at the moment, except for contacting Azure support and having them expire the token.

Comment: OK, thanks. We want to use ADB2C with mobile apps (iOS and Android). We think that it's necessary to have the refresh token revoked when a user change or reset the password, in order to stop the possibility of using the app from another device (which may be stolen or lost, ...). It's critical for us ...

Comment: Hi @user1523812 did you ever find a way of revoking the token?