# Revocation endpoint in Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

Is there a way to revoke a specific refresh token in Azure AD B2C? It's for the user's management of third app and data access delegation.

I only find this method: [Revoke-AzureADUserAllRefreshToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/revoke-azureaduserallrefreshtoken?view=azureadps-2.0)

I don't know if it will work with Azure AD B2C and it clearly doesn't fit with third app management and opt-out.

Comment: According to that users in Azure AD B2C are managed by Azure AD, I think that if  the users which you want to revoke for is in the users in the portal, this powershell cmdlet should also work on it. But,I'm not sure whether it could work for you, I did not test this way. There is a same case in SO, it may be helpful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40083004/revoke-a-refresh-token-on-azure-ad-b2c

Comment: Maybe it will work but clearly it's not our use-case. It will revoke all the refresh tokens, we only want to revoke a specific token according to user opt-out on API data access delegation (third party apps management).

Answer (score 2):

**Outdated, see update below.**
There is no way today to revoke tokens in Azure AD B2C. You can request this via the [Azure AD B2C feedback forum](https://aka.ms/aadb2cuv).

The Revoke-AzureADUserAllRefershToken command only works for regular Azure AD and will not work for Azure AD B2C.

## UPDATE FROM 2018-03-08

**The Revoke-AzureADUserAllRefreshToken command can be used to revoke refresh Azure AD B2C tokens**.

Comment: Ok thanks Saca. Does it means for now there is no way for an end-user who signin (give tokens) on a AD B2C application that targets scopes from another AD B2C application (in the same tenant) to block it if he no longer wants it to access its data ?