# How do you use Revoke-AzureADUserAllRefershToken with Azure AD B2C?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-cloud-shell

I saw this answer and update ([Revocation endpoint in Azure AD B2C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47347034/revocation-endpoint-in-azure-ad-b2c)) but I'm not sure how to use this with Azure AD B2C. I've opened up an Azure Cloud Shell and it comes back that the object ID does not exist. I'm running this from my parent Azure directory because I could not open up an Azure Cloud Shell inside my Azure AD B2C directory (it said "No valid subscription found"). Do you have to run this command from within the Azure AD B2C directory? If so how do I link a subscription so that I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can use Azure Cloud Shell because an Azure AD B2C directory isn't related to an Azure subscription like an Azure AD directory is related to one.

You can use either:

1. [The Revoke-AzureADUserAllRefreshToken cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/Revoke-AzureADUserAllRefreshToken?view=azureadps-2.0) of the Azure Active Directory PowerShell for Graph module.
2. [The Invalidate all refresh tokens for a user operation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/users-operations#invalidate-all-refresh-tokens-for-a-user) of the Azure Active Directory Graph API.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Chris. I tried the 2nd option but get the following result:

<error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<code>Authentication_MissingOrMalformed</code>
<message xml:lang="en">Access Token missing or malformed.</message>
<requestId>328e1694-bbd2-4970-bbf0-26fc1a2b60fc</requestId>
<date>2018-05-08T19:24:01</date>
</error>

Comment: You must acquire an access token as a Global Administrator user from the Azure AD B2C directory before you invoke the Azure AD Graph API. It is easier for experimentation to interact with the Graph API using [the Azure AD Graph Explorer](https://graphexplorer.azurewebsites.net/).

Comment: Thanks again Chris, the Azure AD Graph Explorer is really nice. I signed in as the global administrator and can access everything fine on my main domain but still cannot get access to the B2C directory.

Comment: You must sign in as a global administrator for your Azure AD B2C directory. This administrator must be a user account that is local to this directory. i.e. It can't be a user account from another directory.

Comment: I can try adding another user but the global administrator that I'm signing in as is a member of my main domain and the B2C directory. The user is a Global Administrator in the B2C directory.

Comment: I was able to successfully sign in with a new global adminstrator user and see my users using the graph explorer but unfortunately the "invalidateAllRefreshTokens" request came back with this response:

{
    "odata.error": {
        "code": "Request_BadRequest",
        "message": {
            "lang": "en",
            "value": "Method Not Allowed"
        }
    }
}