# Refresh token revocation in Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

In my AD B2C application,  i need to revoke the all refresh tokens given by AD B2C for a user. This is a requirement to implement as when user account is logged in multiple apps and in one app user changed the password. When password is changed, i have revoke all of his refresh tokens given to other apps.
How to do that?

**Update:**
I have tried following,

1. B2C -Get Token By Policy
   https://login.microsoftonline.com/te/tenantname.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1a_policyname/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
   https://login.microsoftonline.com/te/tenantname.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1a_policyname/oauth2/v2.0/token
   a)Got access token and refresh token using ad b2c user account(created directly through tenant not from sign up policy).
   b)Try to get new access and refresh token by using token end point and grant_type refresh_token -> able to get token
   c)Revoked the token using https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/users/xxxxx-userObjectID-xxxx/invalidateAllRefreshTokens?api-version=1.6
   and client credential flow(a application registered in AD blade of Ad B2C tenant and given access to graph api)
   d)Above token revoke api call is successful and tried step (b).
   e)still able to get new tokens from step(b)
2. B2C -Get Token By Policy - Revoke using GA account
   https://login.microsoftonline.com/te/tenantname.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1a_policyname/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
   https://login.microsoftonline.com/te/tenantname.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1a_policyname/oauth2/v2.0/token
   a)Got access token and refresh token using ad b2c user account(created directly through tenant not from sign up policy).
   b)Try to get new access and refresh token by using token end point and grant_type refresh_token -> able to get token
   c)Revoked the token using https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/users/xxxxx-userObjectID-xxxx/invalidateAllRefreshTokens?api-version=1.6
   and It  is done by logged into graph api explorer using GA account created directly in tenant.
   d)Above token revoke api call is successful and tried step (b).
   e)still able to get new tokens from step(b)
3. B2C -Get Token Without Poicy
   https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantname.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
   https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantname.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/token
   a)Got access token and refresh token using ad b2c user account(created directly through tenant not from sign up policy).
   b)Try to get new access and refresh token by using token end point and grant_type refresh_token -> able to get token
   c)Revoked the token using https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/users/xxxxx-userObjectID-xxxx/invalidateAllRefreshTokens?api-version=1.6
   and client credential flow(a application registered in AD blade of Ad B2C tenant and given access to graph api)
   d)Above token revoke api call is successful and tried step (b).
   e)Not able to get new tokens from step(b)
4. B2C -Get Token Without Poicy - Revoke using GA account
   https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantname.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
   https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantname.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/token
   a)Got access token and refresh token using ad b2c user account(created directly through tenant not from sign up policy).
   b)Try to get new access and refresh token by using token end point and grant_type refresh_token -> able to get token
   c)Revoked the token using https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/users/xxxxx-userObjectID-xxxx/invalidateAllRefreshTokens?api-version=1.6
   It  is done by logged into graph api explorer using GA account created directly in tenant.
   d)Above token revoke api call is successful and tried step (b).
   e)still able to get new tokens from step(b)

Basically not able to revoke the token created from b2c policy workflow.

**Solution:**
Refresh token revoke graph api is working. But it takes around 5 mins to do that.
But Problem here is in between waiting period, i am able to get new refresh token and access token and those new refresh tokens are working even after revocation. Which means Azure AD considered the requested time of refresh token revoke api call and revokes all refresh tokens issued before that time.
So how to avoid that?
When new access token is requested with offline scope using existing refresh token, why does Azure AD provide new refresh token even though existing refresh token has validity time.?

Comment: Hi have you tried out anything? If so, please try to put some sample that  would be easier to have a look on your problem.Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can [invalidate all of the refresh tokens for a specific user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations#invalidate-all-refresh-tokens-for-a-user) using the Azure AD Graph API:

```
POST https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/users/{user_id}/invalidateAllRefreshTokens?api-version=1.6
```

Azure AD Graph API will be deprecated. In the Microsoft Graph API, the documentation is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-revokesigninsessions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) and the call is:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/revokeSignInSessions
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this. It  is not working for refresh token created from B2C through policy. I referred  this link as well (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50064494/how-do-you-use-revoke-azureaduserallrefershtoken-with-azure-ad-b2c?noredirect=1&lq=1). But it is not working. Help me to fix this.

Comment: Hi @Raj How soon (in minutes) after acquiring the refresh token did you invalidate it and how soon after invalidating it did you attempt to redeem it?

Comment: Hi @Chris, i have been trying immediately after calling revoke graph api. I found that it works after 1-5 mins. But i have question here. until it revokes refresh tokens(5 mins waiting period), i am able to get multiple new access_token and refresh token. and those new refresh tokens works even after revocation. How to avoid that?

Comment: When new access token is requested with offline scope using existing refresh token, why does Azure AD provide new refresh token even though existing refresh token has validity time.?

Comment: @Raj did you get any clarity on this subject?

Comment: Any updates ? The way it seems to work means that we can't reliably force user to log out, it's more like "taking a chance".