# Refresh token revocation in Azure AD B2C Custom Policy

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

I have already put question [Refresh token revoke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54887573/refresh-token-revocation-in-azure-ad-b2c) and it works after 1-5mins.
But it works only for inbuilt policy(user flow) not for custom policy.

I have got refresh_token A from inbuilt policy and refresh_token B from custom policy.

Both tokens are received for same user in same tenant.

After executing revoke(Graph API), When i try to get new access and refresh token using refresh_token A, it fails. But when i try with refresh_token B(Received through custom policy), It still works. Able to get new tokens.

I had given 15mins time gap after revoke call.

Please help me fix this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The **Configure the resource owner password credentials flow in Azure Active Directory B2C using a custom policy** article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/ropc-custom) describes the custom elements that must be implemented to manage the refresh tokens and to test that an already-issued one hasn't been invalidated.

You must:

- Create the **refreshTokenIssuedOnDateTime** and **refreshTokensValidFromDateTime** claim types
- Create the **AssertRefreshTokenIssuedLaterThanValidFromDate** claims transformation
- Create the **AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId-CheckRefreshTokenDate** and **SM-RefreshTokenReadAndSetup** technical profiles
- Create the **ResourceOwnerPasswordCredentials-RedeemRefreshToken** user journey
- Refer to this user journey from the **RefreshTokenUserJourneyId** metaproperty of the **JwtIssuer** technical profile

By default, the clock skew is set to 0, but you can change this using the **TreatAsEqualIfWithinMillseconds** parameter of the **AssertRefreshTokenIssuedLaterThanValidFromDate** claims transformation:

```xml
<ClaimsTransformation Id="AssertRefreshTokenIssuedLaterThanValidFromDate" TransformationMethod="AssertDateTimeIsGreaterThan">
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="refreshTokenIssuedOnDateTime" TransformationClaimType="leftOperand" />
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="refreshTokensValidFromDateTime" TransformationClaimType="rightOperand" />
  </InputClaims>
  <InputParameters>
    <InputParameter Id="AssertIfEqualTo" DataType="boolean" Value="false" />
    <InputParameter Id="AssertIfRightOperandIsNotPresent" DataType="boolean" Value="true" />
    <!-- Set the clock skew to 5 minutes (300000 milliseconds). -->
    <InputParameter Id="TreatAsEqualIfWithinMillseconds" DataType="int" Value="300000" />
  </InputParameters>
</ClaimsTransformation>
```

Comment: @Chris, I am having the same issue with a javascript SPA client using an oidc-client. The documentation you point to has a comment at the top that SPA's are not supported. What does this actually mean?

Comment: Hi @DouglasWoods. A SPA shouldn't receive a refresh token because (i) the refresh token represents an account credential, (ii) it must be stored securely, and (iii) it mustn't be exposed client-side. Instead, a SPA can renew an access token, using [silent authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-spa#refresh-tokens).